# How to pass an argument in jquery through url?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

How can i pass argument through url in jquery?

I had my code like this

```
getCIVectorsFormObj.action='getParentChildCIVectors';
```

to this action, i want to add argument

customerID

like

```
getParentChildCIVectors.java?customerID=customerID
```

please help me out.. 
I am struck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use page Name and add query param like this. `getParentChildCIVectors.jsp?customerID=customerID`

Comment: are you using web app and calling a java web page?

Comment: can you share code you are using so that i get context and tell you right solution.

Comment: customerID=document.getElementById('customerID').value;
                        var getCIVectorsFormObj = document.getElementById("ParentChildCICategoryForm");
                        alert("in import ci relation.jsp customerID="+customerID);
                        getCIVectorsFormObj.action='getParentChildCIVectors';

Comment: relation.jsp?customerId=customerID

Comment: getCIVectorsFormObj.action="getParentChildCIVectors?customerId="+customerID;

Comment: document.getElementById('ParentChildCICategoryForm').action = "getParentChildCIVectors.jsp?customerID="+customerID;                      you give example getParentChildCIVectors.java which is not valid in web application. you can write getParentChildCIVectors.jsp

Comment: Then the java file must extend with servelt. and configure this servlet class in your web.xml mapping. and the above code will work. not add java extension

Comment: @ANILBABU: Sajid is right. You don't need the `.java` extension to call servlet

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the arguments as regular Strings:

```
getCIVectorsFormObj.action='getParentChildCIVectors.java?customerID'+customerID;
```

Comment: .java extension can use?

Comment: That's what @user2769354 wanted... You can map your servlet using any suffix you want. I guess this question is about arguments as parameters not about servlet mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Simple it is just **string concatenation** declare one variable `url` as

```
var url = 'getParentChildCIVectors';  //this is your action
```

Now, adding argument is done by

```
url += '?customerID='+customerID;
```

And at last set the action to form as

```
getCIVectorsFormObj.action = url;
```

**Edit**
Passing more parameters then just concatenate

```
url +='customerName='+customerName;  
.......  
..........
```